# CSS3 rotation causing problems IE9

Tags: css, rotation, internet-explorer-9

I am using the following in IE9:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

It works in the way it rotates the text, but oddly it gives the element a black background for no reason?!

The CSS:

```
.view-see-the-difference-in-your-sector .views-field-title span {
   display: block;
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  zoom: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
   width: 200px;
}
```

Also notice I have an origin for all browser rotations apart from the filter one. 
What is the correct syntax to use here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform says that IE9 supports `-ms-transform`. BTW IE9 should ignore the `filter`, because `-ms-filter` took over its place :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of black artifacts on text when using dropshadow filter in IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972723/how-to-get-rid-of-black-artifacts-on-text-when-using-dropshadow-filter-in-ie9)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find this hack that fix the problem for me. You should add filter:none; style to the container with black background. Somehow ie9 does not support filter style used for ie8 so you have to disable it. In your case:

```
.ie9 .view-see-the-difference-in-your-sector .views-field-title span  {
   filter:none;
}
```

You have to detect if your browser is ie9 and add this class to some parent node like the body tag.

Comment: I can't remember where I was or test this since the question was so long ago, but if you have a link or anything else to support your answer I'll vote and accept.

Comment: Ok here is the link with problem solved:
http://apps.radical.ie/st/centra/range_2013/phase_2/tab/.
Sorry that it took me so long to answer, but cant show a project until was finished.

Answer (score 6):

We were using : transform: rotate(45deg); not working in Chrome and IE9.

First Try : Tried solution given in [CSS rotate property in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie/4617511#4617511), it was not working in IE9.

```
       i.e:

        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* FF3.5/3.6 */
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Saf3.1+ */
        transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Solution : Final solution i.e:

```
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* FF3.5/3.6 */
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Saf3.1+ */
         transform: rotate(45deg);  
         -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
          ms-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* This Line did the trick for IE9
```

Found the solution from following URL : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8346