# IE css filter: adding black outline to text - how do I remove it?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I'm trying to add text-shadows to elements in IE - I know it doesn't support the property but using the filter: property I can get it pretty close.

BUT when the text I use is not black there is a black outline around the text.

How can I remove this outline?

Here's an example... (Please open using Internet Explorer)

http://jsfiddle.net/mossman/mLRYG/

Appreciate any help guys, thanks

/* UPDATE */
[image]

Think i'll just have to live with it. Thanks for the direction guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the rendering engine.

[With a large enough font-size, I get no black outline](http://jsfiddle.net/mLRYG/7/).

Since there are no [extra parameters for this filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (except one to disabled it), I guess you gotta *live with it*.

Comment: Where there is a will, there is a way.

Comment: True, politely asking Microsoft to fix this issue might works. :)

Answer (score 1):

I went through and started testing all the combinations or your color choices and then I realized. It might not be you color as the issue. I looked up the correct call for the filter: and found this on the Microsoft site.

[Shadow Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

which gave me this:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow
```

I used that in your example and altered a fiew of the values (because with the correct call you have to use the correct values) and guess what... something looks pretty good.

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#CC0000', Direction=225, Strength=8)
```

I tested this in IE8. Worked great. I added on to your jsFiddle example. Here is the new [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mLRYG/8/) with a working view.

You will also notice that with the official call it doesn't clip the left most shadow on the first letter of the word.

**UPDATE:**

You can try and use the following in conjunction with the .Shadow

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color=#cccccc)
```

Your call would look like this...

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color=#cccccc)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#CC0000', Direction=225, Strength=8)
```

You might have to play around with the Chroma Color, but it should work. I can't test it on this machine (I don't have IE9 on it).

I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187216) post.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate you answer but it didnt solve my problem - I've added a screen of you fiddle in ie9 and the outline is still there.